# Angular ng-class don't work with ngAnimate

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I have the following structure :

```
<div ng-repeat="p in posts">
    <div class="col-1 " ng-class="{'last' : $last}"> ... </div>
</div>
```

It is working good but if i include ngAnimate the ng-class no longer works

I use v.1.4.7 for both angular.js and angular-animate.js

Edited after Julien comment

```
angular.module('uiApp', [ 
                          'ui.router',
                          'ngCookies',
                          'ngStorage',
                          'angular-loading-bar',
                          'ngValidate',
                          'ui.bootstrap',
                          'duScroll',
//                        'ngAnimate',
                          'user.config.module',
                          'ngMeta']).config(
```

and

```
<html ng-app="uiApp">

<body>
  <ui-view /> 
</body>
```

Comment: This [AngularJS issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12267) mentions multiple possible causes and solutions for this issue depending on if you are using angular-material, ui-router, ng-router, where you put the ngApp directive, ... It's way too long to sum it up as an answer. May be you will find your solution inside